# Header not redirecting after submitting form

Tags: php

sorry if ask about this similar header not working problem, this is my code

```
<?php 
include_once 'config/koneksi.php';
session_start();
// LOGIN 
if(isset($_POST['btn_login'])){

    $user = $_POST['txt_user'];
    $pass = $_POST['txt_pass'];

    $select = $pdo->prepare("select * from admin where username='$user' and password='$pass' ");
    $select->execute();

    $row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($row['username']==$user AND $row['password']==$pass){


        $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
        $_SESSION['username']=$row['username'];
        header('location: dashboard/dashboard.php'); 
        exit();

    }else{

    }

    }

?>
```

and this is the url's result after submitting the button and not redirecting to dashboard page

```
http://localhost/bukutamu/?txt_user=admin&txt_pass=admin&btn_login=
```

can anyone help me with this? and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Try adding `ob_start();` just underneath `session_start();`

Comment: is there any whitespace (a empty line or a space) *before* your opening `<?php`?

Comment: i forgot add `session_start();` on next page. thanks